# Linq: Filter a list with a different IEnumerable<bool>

Tags: c#, linq, boolean, ienumerable

I cannot find out how to filter an array/list from another list array:
I was looking for something like this:

```
IEnumerable<bool> Filter = new[] { true, true, false,true };

IEnumerable<string> Names = new[] { "a", "B", "c", "d" };

List<string> NameFiltered = Filter
    .Where(c => c == true)
    .Select(x => Names)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Output is List<string>() {"a","b","c"}. I thought there would be a function similar to Maltab, as I really like Linq I was excpecting somehting I missed. The array indexing is really good idea, but puting everything in a function seems a bit unreadable (plus, I have to recycle the boolean index, it is for grouping from an Excel Table). Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general case (both `Names` and `Filter` are `IEnumerable<T>` only) I suggest `Zip`:

```
List<string> NameFiltered = Names
  .Zip(Filter, (name, filter) => new {
    name = name,
    filter = filter, })
  .Where(item => item.filter)
  .Select(item => item.name)
  .ToList();
```

If `Filter` is in fact an *array* (`..Filter = new[]...`) `Where` will do:

```
List<string> NameFiltered = Names
  .Where((name, index) => Filter[index])
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var NameFiltered = Enumerable.Range(0, Names.Count)
                             .Where(n => Filter[n])
                             .Select(n => Names[n])
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

There's `Zip` method for union of corresponding pairs of two sequences:

```
Filter.Zip(Names, (flag, name) => new { flag, name })
      .Where(x => x.flag)
      .Select(x => x.name)
```

`Zip` makes this:

```
IEnumerable<bool> Filter = new[] { true, true, false, true };

IEnumerable<string> Names = new[] { "a", "B", "c", "d" };

Filter.Zip(Names, (flag, name) => new { flag, name }) =
{
    { flag = true, name = "a" },
    { flag = true, name = "B" },
    { flag = false, name = "c" },
    { flag = true, name = "d" },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but try this:

```
List<string> NameFiltered = Filter
    .Select((x, i) => new { flag = x, index = i })
    .Where(item => item.flag)
    .Select(item => Names.ElementAt(item.index))
    .ToList();
// Output: a, B, d
```

Comment: I'd personally give slightly better names to the properties in your anonymous object to make it more readable.

Comment: Fair enough. My bad, should've spent some more time trying to fix that

Comment: Not a problem. You can edit your post now to improve it if you want. I just looked at `Where(obj => obj.x)` line and got a bit twitchy. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OP wants to filter `Names` using `Filter`, which is made up of `bool` values. If you notice that they have the same number of elements, so if filter is `true`. it is required to be in the resulting set. There are a couple of ways you can achieve this. I would suggest using `Linq.Zip`, which combines two sequences.

```
IEnumerable<bool> Filter = new bool[] { true, true, false, true };
IEnumerable<string> Names = new string[] { "a", "B", "c", "d" };
var merged= Filter.Zip(Names,(bo,str)=> new {bo, str});
var selected = merged.Where(x=> x.bo).Select(y=> y.str);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

used `Where` with index

```
var nameFiltered = Names.Where((x, index) => Filter.ToArray()[index]);
```

Or

```
var nameFiltered= Names.Where((x, index) => Filter.ElementAt(index));
```

Comment: @Yoyo Check this

Answer (score -1):

First of all there is no connection between your collections, so `NameFiltered` list does not know what to return.

I suggest you to make class

```
Names
{

}

public string Name{get;set;}
public bool Fikter{get;set;}


var NameFiltered = Names.Where(x=>x.Fikter == true).toArray;
```

Comment: Format your code and stop using `u` and `ur` as it is not suitable in the Stack Exchange systen.

Comment: I've cleaned up the spelling in your post a bit and marked the code as code. I'm not sure what the code is trying to be though. Is Names a class which should contain the two properties? Or is Names a new list (usage in the last line suggests this)? Your code is very unclear.